# Combine observations based on the variable ID if at least 5 IDs are combined

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, combiners

Last week I posted the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596609/do-a-loop-with-different-versions-of-a-dataset-based-on-a-variable-id-and-save-t) . The idea was to make a loop that determined the content of a database by randomly combining observations based on the variable "id".

For instance:

- dataset 1: combinations of id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8...
- dataset 2: combinations of id 1, 2, 3
- dataset 3: combinations of id 2, 3, 4, 5
- dataset 4: combinations of id 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...

I got a perfect answer to the question:

```
for(i in 2:max(o$id)){
  combis=combn(unique(o$id),i)
  for(j in 1:ncol(combis)){
    sub=o[o$id %in% combis[,j],]
    out=sub[1,]    # use your function
    out$label=paste(combis[,j],collapse ='') #provide an id so you know for which combination this result is
    result=rbind(result,out) # paste it to previous output
  }
}
```

**However, my question now is the following: is there a way to specify that I only want combinations of at least 5 ids combined?** The process takes up a lot of computing time and I noticed that small datasets (with les than 5 different ids) give biased results.

Through this [link](http://Through%20the%20following%20link%20a%20part%20of%20the%20dataset%20can%20be%20found%20with%20the%20code%20necessary.%20drive.google.com/open?id=0By9u5m3kxn9ybi11OEF5NkhkNDQ), a sample of the dataset and the full code can be found to reproduce the example. Please be aware that it can take a while to run the entire code, unless there is something specified that I am only interested in combinations of at least 5 ids.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I recently did this for one of my analyses by creating a "count" column and filtering out any combination/group that was based on fewer than  5 ids.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can optimise that with a mapply statement (which could be parallized as well to speed it up) and (if needed) limit the combination simply by filtering with something like combis[length(combis)>4].  However, I can't be sure as there is no reproducible example... (and the one in your previous post doesn't work (What are AllData and rainfed?)

Comment: I'll make a better example. Give me a minute;-)

Comment: I'll add the question with this dataset and example as well. Through the following link a part of the dataset can be found with the code necessary.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By9u5m3kxn9ybi11OEF5NkhkNDQ There are now 6 different ids in the dataset. Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it a lot! P.S. Be aware that if you run the code as it is now, it takes some time to run. That is the reason why I would like to indicate that I only want the code to run for groups of minimum x ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the loop at 5:

```
for(i in 5:max(o$id)){
  combis=combn(unique(o$id),i)
   ...
```

This way, there are at least 5 elements in each combination (see ?combn).

Comment: So it was that easy.. Thank you once again!